# jquery doesn't work form:select

Tags: jquery, spring-form

I have my form:select like this:

```
<form:select class="select" path="pmiProfile.proProfileNamePk" name="pmiProfile" value="pmiProfile.proProfileNamePk">
    <option value="ROLE_ADMIN" ><spring:message code="pmi.user.add.admin"></spring:message></option>
    <option value="ROLE_USER" ><spring:message code="pmi.user.add.user"></spring:message></option>
</form:select>
```

The jquery, I even used the most simple way:

```
$("select").prop('selectedIndex',1);
```

What I got was: 
The chosen index is well set, but the value showed in the combobox is not changed.
Why?

Generated HTML, you mean this?

```
<div class="form-margin-ten">
    <div class="select2-container select" id="s2id_pmiProfile.proProfileNamePk">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return false;" class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1">
        <span class="select2-chosen">User</span><abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"></abbr>
        <span class="select2-arrow"><b></b></span></a>
        <input class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" type="text" id="s2id_autogen1">
    </div>
    <select id="pmiProfile.proProfileNamePk" name="pmiProfile.proProfileNamePk" class="select select2-offscreen" tabindex="-1">
        <option value="ROLE_ADMIN">Admin</option>
        <option value="ROLE_USER">User</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Please use the generated HTML output in your JSFiddle, not the spring-form source. We need to see the client-side version :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:
$("select option:eq(1)").prop("selected", true)

Comment: Isn't that converting a jQuery object to a DOM object then trying to call the jQuery prop method? I was not aware that DOM elements had a prop method?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this gives the same thing. when I click the combbox, the chosen index is '1', but the valued shown in the combox is not the value of item index 1. In fact, this jquery works fine in the other JSP pages, but just won't work on this one. weird.

Comment: I suspect that it has something to do with a ui framework that you are using. Looking at your example html the elements have an xml prefix / namespace. So I am assuming that something such as a ui framework is processing the html to render out the browser control. Maybe the underlying DOM is being updated but the ui control is not.

Comment: @TomMaher well yes u r right, there's a ui file about custom select tag. I removed it and the select worked. what's weird is, this custom select work fine in the other pages, and I didn't find much difference between the page work and dont-work, gonna ask the one who wrote the ui js

Answer (score 0):

How about:
$("select").attr("selectedIndex", 1);

Comment: I suspect that it probably has something to do with spring form. From what you've said the underlying DOM objects are being updated which means that jQuery is working. However there seems to be a disconnect between the DOM object an the ui control. I've not used spring form but am guessing it's some sort of framework for rendering ui elements. It might be worth looking at a DOM inspector in your browser to just make sure that the html of the ui control is the same html that you're setting with the jQuery. As it maybe that spring is generating html based on your html.